# The composition of a dissipative operator and a positive operator is dissipative?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, operator-theory

Consider the following bilinear system on a open and bounded domain $\Omega$
    \begin{equation}
  \left\{\begin{array}{r c l}
  \displaystyle\frac{dy(t)}{dt} &=& Ay(t)+u(t)By(t)\\
  y(0) &=& y_0
  \end{array}
  \right.
  \end{equation}
    where the state space is $ H^1(\Omega)$  endowed with
    its usual inner product, denoted by $\langle ., . \rangle$ and  $\|.\|$ the associated norm, the operator $A$ generates   a semigroup of contractions $S(t)$ on $H^1(\Omega)$,   $u(t)$ is a scalar valued control and  $B$ is a linear and bounded  operator mapping  $H^1(\Omega)$ into itself.

Suppose that this system  admits a unique mild solution $y$.

Since $A$ generates a semigroup of contractions then from  Lumer-Phillips Theorem $A$ is dissipative ($\langle Ay,y\rangle \leq 0$),
moreover we have $G = \nabla^*\nabla$ is positive ($\langle Gy,y\rangle = \langle \nabla y,\nabla y\rangle = \|\nabla y\|^2_{(L^2(\Omega))^n} \geq 0$).

So in this case, are there some sufficient assumptions on $A$ that guarantees $\langle GAy,y\rangle \leq 0$?